# Python: Have gifs animate with TKinter while a thread is running

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.7, animated-gif

So, as I'm sure you can tell from my rather long subject what I'm asking but to reiterate. I am trying to have a gif animate while a thread in the background is running a calculation with in TKinter. For simplicities sake, I am using this gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fqLp.gif

The gif animation is currently working as you can see if you run the script. But as soon as the Generate button is pressed and the thread initiates, the gif pauses until it finishes. I'm using time.sleep() to simulate the large amount of calculations that I will be doing in the background (though I am unsure if this is what is actually causing the issue).

I'm sure it has something to do with not understanding exactly how the animation is functioning. Any advice?

Code as follows:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import time
import os
import threading
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Gif(Label):
    def __init__(self, master, filename):
        evanGif = Image.open(filename)
        gifSeq = []
        try:
            while 1:
                gifSeq.append(evanGif.copy())
                evanGif.seek(len(gifSeq)) # skip to next frame
        except EOFError:
            pass # we're done
        try:
            #Special case for the evangalion gif
            if evanGif.info['duration'] == 0:
                self.delay = 100
            else:
                self.delay = evanGif.info['duration']
        except KeyError:
            self.delay = 100
        gifFirst =gifSeq[0].convert('RGBA')
        self.gifFrames = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(gifFirst)]

        Label.__init__(self, master, image=self.gifFrames[0])

        temp =gifSeq[0]
        for image in gifSeq[1:]:
            temp.paste(image)
            frame = temp.convert('RGBA')
            self.gifFrames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(frame))

        self.gifIdx = 0
        self.cancel = self.after(self.delay, self.play)

    def play(self):
        self.config(image=self.gifFrames[self.gifIdx])
        self.gifIdx += 1
        if self.gifIdx == len(self.gifFrames):
            self.gifIdx = 0
        self.cancel = self.after(self.delay, self.play)

class App:
    generating = False
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master

        #Initializing frames
        self.buttonFrame = Frame(master, background='light gray')
        self.loadingFrame = Frame(master, background='light gray')
        self.loadingFrame.grid(row=0)
        self.buttonFrame.grid(row=1)
        self.anim = Gif(self.loadingFrame, '4Y9UJ.gif').pack()
        self.update_Thread = threading.Thread(target=time.sleep, args=(5,))
        self.buttonSetup()

    def buttonSetup(self):
        #ALL THE BUTTONS
        self.generateBt = Button(self.buttonFrame, text="Generate!", command=self.generate, background='light gray', highlightbackground='light gray')
        self.generateBt.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.quitBt = Button(self.buttonFrame, text="Quit!", fg="red", command=self.buttonFrame.quit, background='light gray', highlightbackground='light gray')
        self.quitBt.pack(side=LEFT)

    def generate(self):
        self.hideForGen()
        self.update_Thread.start()
        while(self.update_Thread.isAlive()):
            self.master.update_idletasks()
        self.reset()
        self.master.update_idletasks()
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Complete", "Report generation completed!")

    def hideForGen(self):
        self.buttonFrame.grid_forget()

    def reset(self):
        self.buttonFrame.grid(row=1)

root = Tk()
root.title('Test')
root.configure(background='light gray')
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is in your generate() method.
That while loop is unnecessary.

Bear in mind that you can't re-start a thread.
If you want to use the generate button multiple times, you'll need to create a new thread each time.

```
class App:
    generating = False
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master

        #Initializing frames
        self.buttonFrame = Frame(master, background='light gray')
        self.loadingFrame = Frame(master, background='light gray')
        self.loadingFrame.grid(row=0)
        self.buttonFrame.grid(row=1)
        self.anim = Gif(self.loadingFrame, '4Y9UJ.gif')
        self.anim.pack()
##        self.update_Thread = threading.Thread(target=time.sleep, args=(5,))

        self.buttonSetup()

    def buttonSetup(self):
        #ALL THE BUTTONS
        self.generateBt = Button(self.buttonFrame, text="Generate!", command=self.generate, background='light gray', highlightbackground='light gray')
        self.generateBt.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.quitBt = Button(self.buttonFrame, text="Quit!", fg="red", command=self.buttonFrame.quit, background='light gray', highlightbackground='light gray')
        self.quitBt.pack(side=LEFT)

    def wait_generate(self):
        if self.update_Thread.isAlive():
            self.master.after(500, self.wait_generate)
        else:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo("Complete", "Report generation completed!")
            self.reset()

    def generate(self):
        self.hideForGen()
        self.update_Thread = threading.Thread(target=time.sleep, args=(5,))
        self.update_Thread.start()
##        while(self.update_Thread.isAlive()):
##            self.master.update_idletasks()
##        self.reset()
##        self.master.update_idletasks()
##        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Complete", "Report generation completed!")
        self.wait_generate()

    def hideForGen(self):
        self.buttonFrame.grid_forget()

    def reset(self):
        self.buttonFrame.grid(row=1)
```

Comment: I realized the issue with the thread after I posted this. I didn't know about the after method, that does make the while loop unnecassary and cuts down on the loops that I need to do. However, I am having some issues with gifs where the subsequent frames only add onto the previous frames. i.e. i.imgur.com/Q6CBO.gif
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In the method below:

```
    def generate(self):
        self.hideForGen()
        self.update_Thread.start()
        while(self.update_Thread.isAlive()):
            self.master.update_idletasks()
        self.reset()
        self.master.update_idletasks()
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Complete", "Report generation completed!")
```

If you put

```
    self.master.update()
```

instead of

```
    self.master.update_idletasks()
```

it should work. At least it did for me.

Comment: I'll give it a shot when I get home but thanks for the response. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: That totally worked. However, I am having some issues with gifs where the subsequent frames only add onto the previous frames.
i.e. http://i.imgur.com/Q6CBO.gif